# Python: how to specific & build & clean files with distutils

Tags: python, cython, distutils

I'm trying to compile my project using Cython and I'm using distutils with this case.

My project look like this :

```
> ProjectFolder
    > folder1
        --> 1.py
        --> 2.py

    > folder2
        --> 3.py
        --> 4.py

    start.py
    setup.py
```

And what I'm looking for is compile all python files inside : folder1 and put these files after compile inside folder1.

Also compile all python files inside : folder2 and put these files after compile inside folder2.

And at the end compile start.py file and put it in same dir.

After compiling these files I want to remove all c file who have .c extension.

What I'm starting with inside setup.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(["folder1/1.py", "folder2/2.py"])
)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: http://nfoti.github.io/a-creative-blog-name/posts/2013/02/07/cleaning-cython-build-files/